# Facebook Graph API GraphMethodException 100

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am calling the following Graph API with access tokens issued by two different apps:

```
/v2.3/{user_id}?access_token={access_token}
```

First call works, second returns the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100
  }
}
```

Apps have the same settings in the Facebook dashboard. I can't find what's causing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the same ID for both and it's not a Global then one of the calls will always be guaranteed to fail.

Graph API 2.0+ uses app scoped IDs, that is, the ID you obtain in the application is unique and cannot be used outside of that calling application.

So

- `/v2.3/{user_id_from_app_1}?access_token={access_token_app_1}` Always work
- `/v2.3/{user_id_from_app_1}?access_token={access_token_app_2}` Always fail
- `/v2.3/{user_id_from_app_2}?access_token={access_token_app_2}` Always work

Comment: That was the problem. Thanks!